# jQuery - Add this val() as Class

Tags: list, class

I've been trying to add a class to each list item based on their content:

```
$('.cl-tags').children('li').addClass( $(this).val() );
```

From

```
<ul class="cl-tags">
  <li>Green</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>BLue</li>
  <li>Yellow</li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul class="cl-tags">
  <li class"Green">Green</li>
 ...
```

Apparently jQuery throws an error, is there other way of doing this?

Comment: Please include the code as well as the error, and some relevant HTML

Comment: Try this.text() instead of this.val()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery('.cl-tags').children('li').each(function( index ) {
   jQuery(this).addClass( jQuery(this).text() );    
});
```

or

```
$('.cl-tags').children('li').each(function( index ) {
   $(this).addClass($(this).text());    
});
```

hope this will help you